# Device orientation towards iBeacon

Tags: ios, ios7, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm starting to work with Bluetooth LE and iBeacons on iOS7.

I downloaded a little piece of code RFduino from OpenSourceRF.com to get the relative RSSI power of the beacon. This allows me to get a finest notion of proximity between the sender and the receiver then the default proximity callbacks.

I wondered if it was possible to have a notion of device orientation (the beacon is on the left) since iBeacons uses CoreLocation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS CoreLocation simply uses the RSSI measurement to estimate distance.  See an explanation of how this works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434019/1461050).

**This technique does not allow a directional estimate**, because the signal strength generally declines in proportion to the distance from the beacon in any direction.  Unless you have multiple iBeacon in the same spot with unidirectional antennas, I do not think there is any way to estimate direction.  To my knowledge nobody makes unidirectional Bluetooth antennas.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what I told my manager but I wanted to be sure ;)