# iBeacon: How can I put custom data into advdata?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I want to put custom data, like User ID, into advdata of iBeacon packet. Is it possible? If so, how can I get the data. CLBeaconRegion seems not to have the advdata property.

Please take a look the great sample of iBeacon below. https://github.com/suwa-yuki/BeaconSample/blob/master/BeaconSender/BeaconSender/BSViewController.m

As far as I can see, I may put custom measuredPower into the advertisement data. Can I use this property as a custom variable? I mean I want to put UserId into the measuredPower property. Does it affect RSSI or other things?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put any bytes into an iBeacon advertisement that you wish, but iOS severely limits which of these bytes you can read.  If you need to use iOS to read these data, you only have four bytes of bluetooth advdata you can change that will be readable by iOS.  If you only care about reading the bytes with other operating systems (OSX Mavericks, Android, Linux) then this is not a problem.

To explain the limits of iOS, it helps to take a look at the advdata of a typical iBeacon advertisement, which looks like this:

```
4C 00 # Company identifier code (0x004C == Apple)
02 15 # iBeacon advertisement indicator
e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 # ProximityUUID
00 00 # Major 
00 00 # Minor 
c5 # The 2's complement of the MeasuredPower
```

iOS does not allow you to access the raw bytes of the advdata shown above using its `CoreBluetooth` APIs.  (See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html) for more details.)  If you use the iBeacon ranging functions of `CoreLocation`, you can read the `ProximityUUID` (16 bytes), `Major` (2 bytes) and `Minor` (2 bytes) out of the advdata.  The `MeasuredPower` that is set in the code example you mentioned is **NOT** directly readable in iOS.  It simply is used as an input to the algorithm used to estimate distance from the RSSI. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20434019/1461050) for details.) Changing the `MeasuredPower` in the advertisement will affect this distance estimate, but you can not reliably determine the actual `MeasuredPower` value.  So you cannot use it as a custom variable.

As described above, an iBeacon advertisement also includes a 16-byte `ProximityUUID`.  But the iOS `CoreLocation` APIs don't let you see any iBeacon advertisements unless you specify the matching `ProximityUUID` up front.  So it really isn't any use as a custom variable.

What can you use as a custom variable?  The two values you **can** use for custom variables are the `Major` field and the `Minor` fields.  Each of these is two bytes and if you tell iOS `CoreLocation` to range all iBeacons that have a given `ProximityUUID`, you will get ranging updates telling you the `Major` and `Minor` values for each, and you can encode any data in these fields you want.  To access these, use simply read the values like this:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    for (CLBeacon *iBeacon in iBeacons) {
        // write code here to do something with iBeacon.major and iBeacon.minor
        // which each will have values from 0-65535
    }        
}
```

All of the above is an iOS-only restriction.  Other platforms let you see the full bytes of the advdata, so you can use any of the bytes you want as custom variables.  If you still want them to be recognized as iBeacons, however, you should leave the second two bytes (the iBeacon advertisement indicator) alone.

For custom variables, the best practice is to use lookup table to tie the standard iBeacon identifiers (`ProximityUUID`, `Major`, `Minor`) to data fields.  This lookup table can be embedded in your app, or it can use a web service like Radius Networks' [ProximityKit](http://proximitykit.com) to do do this automatically.

Full disclosure:  I am Chief Engineer for Radius Networks.

Comment: I didn't think of that I can use the major or minor as a custom variable. The 2bit is enough value to specific identity in my case and the number of beacons is lower than 65536. Therefore, I can use the minor value as a custom variable. Thanks so much!

Comment: As far as I understand it, the minor is suppsed to be THE custom variable.

Comment: @davidgyound Hello, I would like to ask if this information still holds. I can see that the answer is over a year and half old. Were there any changes or on iOS you can still only use 4 bytes for variable information?

Comment: I think this is still true.  You may have some more specifics you want to ask (I saw you added more info in a deleted answer.)  I did have some further thoughts on your other points if you want to ask a new question and link to it from here.