# Determine the exact distance of the Beacon

Tags: ios, ibeacon, proximity, ios7.1

Can we determine the exact distance of the Beacon from the iOS App using these properties below.

1. Proximity
2. accuracy
3. rssi

If so, How can we achieve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried reading the Docs and running the example applications?

Comment: How should you be able to determine *exact* distance without trigonometry... all the above won't be sufficient to give exact distance, the values will always be ambiguous.

Comment: Hope these post will help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416218/understanding-ibeacon-distancing)

Comment: @Volker - the value will be ambiguous with trigonometry, too, though having more measurements may improve things.

Answer (score 1):

accuracy is an estimation of the distance (in meter) between your device and the beacon. It isn't really reliable. As a matter of fact determining an exact distance would require taking into account all things creating interferences or attenuating the signal which isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy is reliable within `1 meter`,but the value may `fluctuate`.With increasing distance error increases.

You can calculate the distance by `rssi` in the actual environment.