# Implementation of iBeacon technology in Android

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I want to develop a App which recognizes the beacon just like the iBeacon technology that Apple has created for iOS apps.

Does Googles Android has similar technology like the Apple's iBeacon or Is there any third party library available for supporting beacons detection?

Thanks,

Comment: It should work on any device that has Bluetooth LE. Maybe it needs some workarounds on some devices but it sure is possible.

Answer (score 1):

My company has released the open source [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/), which handles detection and ranging of beacons.

Comment: Can you please share the Algorithm that you are using calculating the proximity.

Comment: I think this will work. [Formula ->](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416218/understanding-ibeacon-distancing)