# How to calculate distance between android and iphone using rssi value

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, ibeacon-android

I am trying to read distance between android which scans for devices which advertises and iphone which act as an advertiser, using Bluetooth Low Energy ie BLE.

Now using the rssi value is there any alogorithm through which approximate distance between android and iphone can be found?

Using android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback's call back method onLeScan , I am not always able to scan the advertised iphone device. But always iBeacon is able to get in the scanned device list.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) has a built in function that estimates distance.  A description of the feature is here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html

You can see a discussion of how this works here:

[Understanding ibeacon distancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416218/understanding-ibeacon-distancing)