# Whats the connection between configured signal strength and measured RSSI (iBeacon related)

Tags: bluetooth, signals, ibeacon, rssi, energy

I hope someone can help me.

I'm a bit confused. I read really much about configuring iBeacon in the last time but I'm not getting one thing, especially after a few tests:

I made an iBeacon out of a Raspberry Pi. Everything works, fine. I tried to find out, what's hidden inside the command

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 92 77 83 0A B2 EB 49 0F A1 DD 7F E3 8C 49 2E DE 00 00 00 00 C5 00.
```

The pair before the last one ("C5") describes the calibrated signal strength as far as I know. I tried some configurations from 00 to FF. (Just to make sure: (C5)hex means (197)dec, right?)

Are there some borders which I have to pay attention to? I read it goes from -1 (strongest) to -127 (weakest).

I measured the RSSI with Locate Beacon from the AppStore an compared them and now I'm not sure, which configuration is highest signal power and which is lowest.

The RSSI at the iPhone should be Highest RSSI (let's say -1 - -15) is strongest, the lowest (-90 - -75) is weakest, right?

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

The calibrated signal strength is a one byte signed integer.  To convert it to a signed decimal number, first convert it to an unsigned decimal, then if it is > 127 subtract 128.

C5 Hex ->  197 Unsigned Decimal -> -59 Signed Decimal

The units are dBm, more negative numbers represent weaker signals.  Less negative numbers represent stronger signals.

You can read some details about how this works here: [Understanding ibeacon distancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416218/understanding-ibeacon-distancing)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the link to the other problem. Do you know, where I can find out the borders of the calibrated signal strength? Or is it just between the range of -128 and 127?