# How to find the nearby user location using Bluetooth instead of GPS?

Tags: android, bluetooth, location

I want to find my nearby app users location by using their bluetooth and show their location in a map. I know that using bluetooth we can only trace unto 10 meters only and that is not a problem for me. Can anyone suggest me the right direction to start with?

Comment: Hi, could you descripbe your use case a bit more? You are programming an App? And this app should locate the device the app is running on or other user using the same app? Is it about using BLE?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about BLE. At least that is the must suitable soltuion.

On Android you can read the RSSI value of nearby devices from the BLE scan response. You  have got two possible ways there:

1. Asume a default RSSI value in 1 m distance
2. Read the Tx Power level from the advertisement if this value is present. For more information see [What exactly is txPower for Bluetooth LE and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862185/what-exactly-is-txpower-for-bluetooth-le-and-how-is-it-used)

From the RSSI value of the received advertisements you can estimate the distance, More or less.
If you see the "[Accessory Design Guidelines for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf)" you will notice that at least apple suitable devices should contain the Tx Power level in their advertisement data.

Moreover the BLE standard provides some characteristic to transmit a beacons position. Search for location on: 
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics

So in general, any device can provide it's TxPowerLevel in 1m distance and it's location by BLE characteristics. Now it is dependent on what you actually want to do. Locate other BLE beacon? Or locate your user be the detection of known beacon? Both is possible by using the mentioned data.