# iBeacon: Linear Approximation Model (LAM)

Tags: swift, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

first i want to calibrate my Beacons, so for this i go 1 meter away and get 60 rssi values and take the average of them. Then I have the receiving signal power at 1m distance from my beacon. 
Now I want to calculate the distance based on the following formula:
[image]

A represents the receiving signal power at 1 meter distance
K represents the exponent of the path loss
d represents the distance

K depends on the room, in which i want to calculate the distance. What is the best course of action to calculate the variable K for this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to solve for K and A.  To do this, you need to repeat the calibration procedure for other distances to get more data points so you have multiple d values and multiple RSSI values.  Then you need to run a regression to find the best fit values for K and A.

That said, I doubt you will have much success with this formula.  I have not been able to use it to accurately predict distance.  I have found [this formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416218/understanding-ibeacon-distancing) to be a better predictor.

Comment: Have you looked into this paper? https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fupcommons.upc.edu%2Fpfc%2Fbitstream%2F2099.1%2F22364%2F4%2Fblepositioning_thesis_corbacho.pdf&ei=QJiSVfDiH8S2UcDfgOgG&usg=AFQjCNG7szw6WGuTeOYpxSvqwNPV3BI1-A&bvm=bv.96783405,d.d24                                  On page 40 they use a Log distance model. But there you have also to get unknown variables like n and X(g). Do I have to get them also with experimental data?

Comment: Yes.  You must get them with experimental data.  The values are different for each beacon transmitter and mobile device receiver.