# Estimote Beacons Distance Calculation

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, estimote

Im coding an android project (using EstimoteSDK) where I need to detect distance from my beacons, that's because I want to handle them as "detected" from maximum 1.5 meters. 
Should I do it using rssi & txpower? and if so, how do I get them using EstimoteSDK and put them into an equation`?

Comment: Yep, the ratio of RSSI and TxPower is proportional to the distance, but the signal strength will vary and there's no one "absolute truth" as for what formula to use. David Young has written about trying to replicate the corresponding behaviour in iOS in the [Understanding ibeacon distancing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416218/understanding-ibeacon-distancing) and in more detail in the [Fundamentals of Beacon Ranging blog post](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html) on the Radius Network website.

Answer (score 0):

**The Estimote SDK has a built in method for calculating distance.**

import com.estimote.sdk.Utils;

"DEFINE A BEACON ETC- BEACON_1"

Utils.computeAccuracy(BEACON_1)