# Mock testing for BLE signals emitting?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am working with a beacon application(android), I am new with beacon and i did not get the full idea of the shortest path identification using beacons.

1-How to find the shortest path using beacons signal?

2-Can we emit the BLE signals using any application(I need to test it initially before purchasing beacons)

3-Please share if you have any good source code git hub for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "1-How to find the shortest path using beacons signal?" Are you talking distance estimation?

Comment: right, i need to take distance estimation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can estimate the distance to a beacon on Android, but it only works well at short distances of 1-3 meters as the signal gets so weak relative to radio noise at greater distances that you really can't tell the difference between a signal that is 20 meters away and 10 meters away.  Another important factor is that each Android device model has a different receiving antenna with its own gain, so some pick up stronger signals than others.  You must factor this into your distance calculation.

A lot of work has been done on this in the open source Android Beacon Library.  You can read more about how it estimates distance here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html

If you are looking for a basic formula to find distance based on signal strength, check my answer here: [Understanding ibeacon distancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416218/understanding-ibeacon-distancing)  However, keep in mind this simple answer does not account for the factors described above.

You can easily simulate transmitting a beacon signal using an Android app like Locate: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en

Full disclosure:  I am the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library project and the author of the Locate app.